# Long.parseLong giving NumberFormatException

Tags: java, long-integer

My issue is that

```
checksum = Long.parseLong("-986.9");
```

is giving NumberFormatException.
Isn't this a parsible long?

Comment: No. It's a float (single or double precision).

Answer (score 5):

A `Long` is not a decimal. Use `Double` and convert :

```
Double.parseDouble("-986.9").longValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. A `long` is a numeric integer type, and your number has a decimal point.

You want a `double` here (ie `Double.parseDouble()`).

Answer (score 0):

long is an integer data type, -986.9 is not an integer. The below works for me.

```
long checksum = Long.parseLong("-986");
    System.out.println(checksum);
    double checksum2 = Double.parseDouble("-986.6");
    System.out.println(checksum2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a double, use the method `Double.parseDouble(var)`